# Did any Advaitin claim that Sayanacharya interpreted Vedas wrongly in his commentaries?

Tags: vedas, advaita, commentary, sayanacharya

Sayanacharya wrote Bhashyas/commentaries on Vedas. Did any Advaita Acharya or any Advaitins ever claim that Sayanacharya's Bhashyas have errors?

Comment: No Sayanacharya has fairly correct interpretation.

Comment: But in sayanacharya bhashya . there is some bad things . the Christians are supporting that . sayana tell that Bali of animal . when we see according to sayana bali achara in Ramayana the any animals where kill and in same Ramayana human Bali will be there

Comment: That’s the job of missionaries. Why else are they called missionaries? They’re not happy in life so they want to badmouth others.

Comment: When what is your uttar paksha to missionaries . or you leave purva paksha of missionaries and do conversations

Comment: You don’t talk to them. They’re not worth it.

Comment: When how to stop conversations . when we can can give uattar pasksha when Normal Hindus go to conversations

Comment: Don’t give Uttara paksha. The more Uttara paksha you give the more they will irritate. Leave them alone. Just prevent others from getting affected by them

Comment: When we can not give uttara parksha how can we stop conversations

Comment: If someone is getting converted then that's their fate. Its not that they are first checking arguments and based on that they are deciding. According to Hinduism everything is predetermined. So you need not worry about things that are beyond our control. Sayana's interpretation is correct. There are many ways of interpreting Vedas. Sayana followed one among those ways.@PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

Comment: You believe animal sacrifice is there in Vedas

Comment: Also how is killing animals or eating meat an argument that missionaries use for conversion? They are not vegetarian isn't it? The converted persons won't have any restrictions about eating meat. @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

Comment: Sir once see the Ramayana many animals where killed when we follow sayanacharya bhashya

Comment: Killing in sacrifice is non killing. So there is no sin involved. @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud. Animal sacrifice is an important part of Vedic rituals. One Upanishad even says that animals were created by Brahma for the sake of sacrifice. Animals which are properly sacrificed to deities reach higher planes like heavens.

Comment: When we can kill 100s of animals